# How to convert a time object to seconds since midnight in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a `datetime.time` object (no date part) in python, and want to find out how many seconds has elapsed since midnight.  `t.hour * 3600 + t.minute * 60 + t.second` will surely work, but is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `datetime.combine()` to create a `datetime` object, to get `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

td = datetime.combine(datetime.min, t) - datetime.min
seconds = td.total_seconds() # Python 2.7+
integer_milliseconds = td // timedelta(milliseconds=1) # Python 3
```

It supports microseconds and any other future `datetime.time.resolution`.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, it seems you can't get a `timedelta` object from two `datetime.time` objects. However, you can build one and use it with `total_seconds()` to get the number of seconds since midnight:

```
In [63]: t = datetime.time(hour=12, minute=57, second=12)  # for example
In [64]: datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute,
                            seconds=t.second).total_seconds()
Out[64]: 46632.0
```